# Check for value within test of TestCafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I use TestCafe to automate testing a specific function. In this function, the user is only allowed to have 5 entries. On the site is a label that indicates how many entries are left. 
When the user already has 5 entries it should delete one in order to test adding a new one. 
The html markup of the page is:

```
<p class="pull-left text-muted">5 / 5 possible entries</p>
```

Now I want to get exactly this string to make a little if/else with JavaScript to delete an entry when it says 5 / 5 possible entries. So far I have this test-code:

```
await t
    .expect(location.pathname).eql(addresspath);

const extractEntries = Selector("p").withText("possible entries");
console.log('[DEBUG], Entries: ' + extractEntries.toString());
var entries = extractEntries.toString().substring(0, 1);
console.log('[DEBUG], character: ' + entries);
```

When the test runs, on the output of extractEntries.toString() outputs this:

```
[DEBUG], Entries: function __$$clientFunction$$() {
        var testRun = builder.getBoundTestRun() || _testRunTracker2.default.resolveContextTestRun();
        var callsite = (0, _getCallsite.getCallsiteForMethod)(builder.callsiteNames.execution);
        var args = [];

        // OPTIMIZATION: don't leak `arguments` object.
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args.push(arguments[i]);
        }return builder._executeCommand(args, testRun, callsite);
    }
```

And the next line:

```
[DEBUG], character: f
```

I have tried `extractEntries.textContent`, `extractEntries.innerHTML`, `extractEntries.innerText` but I am not able to get the text `5 / 5 possible entries`.

What would be the solution to access the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe Selectors provide asynchronous properties to obtain element state values. To get element text, call the `textContent` property with the `await` directive:

```
const paragraph      = Selector("p").withText("possible entries");
const extractEntries = await paragraph.textContent;
```