# Testcafe get text from element

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to get a text from a modal on Chrome. Using the console, I can get the inner text as follows:

```
document.querySelector('.my-form > a').innerText
// returns http://a-url.com
```

Now, on my test, I can evaluate the element using

```
const myText = Selector('.my-form > a').innerText;
await t
  .expect(myText).contains('url');
```

and I can even click on that URL

```
await t.click(myText);
```

but I cannot put that inner text to a variable, for instance. I tried using a ClientFunction from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54415827/how-i-can-get-text-from-web-element-and-print-in-console-for-example)

```
const getUrl = ClientFunction(() => document.querySelector('.my-form > a').innerText);

test('My Test', async t => {
const text = await getUrl();
console.log(text);
});

// this results in 
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

and tried using a plain Selector as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770606/check-for-value-within-test-of-testcafe) suggests

```
const text = Selector('.my-form > a').innerText;
const inner = await text.textContent;
console.log(inner);

// prints: undefined
```

How to extract a text from an element? I understand that `t.selectText` is limited in this scenario, right?

Comment: You shouldn't need a client function, Your last example is incorrect, did you try:
```const text = await Selector('.my-form >a').innerText;``` ?

Note if there are multiple ```a``` tags in your form you will get all the text

Comment: It works! @ioseph Do you want to answer so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html) you want:

`const text = await Selector('.my-form > a').innerText;`

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I kept wrapping my selector to try and clean up the text I was getting. This worked great.

Answer (score 2):

That will do the trick:

```
const paragraph      = Selector("p").withText("possible entries");
const extractEntries = await paragraph.textContent;
```